# White bottom & top bars on full screen in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I've Google my butt off and I haven't found a solution or a similar problem yet. (Maybe it's my Google Skills today) but I'm having a full-screen problem.

I'm using the code below to let my website go full screen.

```
function toggleFullscreen(elem) {
  elem = elem || document.documentElement;
  if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
    !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

But when you go full screen, you get a white bar on top, and a white bar below the actual website, like this.

[image]

I've tried different ways of solving it, using :full-screen in the css and using different methods: html5 or JavaScript.

[Check out the website and problem on CodePen right here.](https://codepen.io/W1ckeD/pen/MmGPNO)

Thank you for your time, hopefully somebody has an answer to this very annoying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below to your css

```
:-webkit-full-screen 
        {
            background-color: red;
        }
```

Similarly you can add for moz and ms.

Please check this link for more details
[Full Screen API Tutorial](http://qnimate.com/full-screen-api-tutorial-with-demo/)